# mysqli prepared statement with fetch_assoc

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

my goal here is to be able to get a variable (with php) and use it in a prepared statement (with mysqli), and then fetch_assoc. For some reason this code will not work (no errors). I've rtm and I haven't found anything combining fetch_assoc with prepared statements, so I'm not sure if it's even possible. Any help to get this working is appreciated, here's my code currently.

```
$where = $_GET['section'];
            $mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","test");

            if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli,"SELECT title, img, active, price FROM ? ORDER by ID limit 5 ")){
                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $where);
                mysqli_stmt_execute($mysqli);
                mysqli_stmt_fetch($mysqli);
                 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)){
                    if($row['active']=="yes"){
                        echo 'the rest of my stuff goes here';
```

Comment: dynamic table selection is usually an indication of bad design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the PHP website page for [mysqli->prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php) (with emphasis added to the most relevant part):

> Note:
>
> The markers are legal only in certain places in SQL statements. For
>   example, they are allowed in the VALUES() list of an INSERT statement
>   (to specify column values for a row), or in a comparison with a column
>   in a WHERE clause to specify a comparison value.
>
> ***However, they are not allowed for identifiers (such as table or column
>   names)***, in the select list that names the columns to be returned by a
>   SELECT statement), or to specify both operands of a binary operator
>   such as the = equal sign. The latter restriction is necessary because
>   it would be impossible to determine the parameter type. In general,
>   parameters are legal only in Data Manipulation Language (DML)
>   statements, and not in Data Definition Language (DDL) statements.

Assuming you can get past that problem, your use of `mysqli` is a little confused. You correctly bind your parameters and execute, but you've mixed up two different ways of getting at your results. Either

1. Use `mysqli_stmt_get_result` to fetch the result set and then use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` on that, or
2. Bind your results with `mysqli_stmt_bind_result`, and then use `mysqli_stmt_fetch` to fetch the next set of results into your bound variables. (Usually you'd iterate over the results using something like `while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){ //do stuff here }`

Comment: @PinheadLarry Okay, I've added a bit about using prepared statements because your use in your example code doesn't seem to be quite right.

Answer (score -2):

Another way style, we can write it below:

```
$mysqli=new mysqli("host","user","pass","db");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $variable);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
....
}
```